# Sql Server 2012 store pdf

Tags: jquery, sql-server, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-2

How to store PDFs file in database and how to show preview using the asp.net. the PDFs file is uploaded by  control and then i need to show preview afterward i store into the database.

```
    <input type="file" />
```

Comment: [FILESTREAM MVC: Download and Upload images from SQL Server](http://rusanu.com/2011/02/06/filestream-mvc-download-and-upload-images-from-sql-server/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, you can choose one of the following techniques:

- Upload the file in specific folder in your server and store in your database only the `URL` to the file. Latter, use the `URL` for showing or downloading the file
- Upload the file and store in the database in `BLOB` (`B`inary `L`arge `OB`ject) field

Each of these, has advantages and disadvantages and it is up to your situation and you to decided which technique for use.

Fortunately, when we are using SQL Server for storing files we have one more option which can lead to better performance - [Filestream Storage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

This type of storage is recommended in the following situations:

- Objects that are being stored are, on average, larger than 1 MB.
- Fast read access is important.
- You are developing applications that use a middle tier for
  application logic

Since, rarely PDF files are smaller then 1 MB, I believe you should use this technique but:

> For smaller objects, storing varbinary(max) BLOBs in the database
>   often provides better streaming performance.

You can check the following [this](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/an-introduction-to-sql-server-filestream/) tutorial in order to activate the storage.