# how to store image in Sql Server with php

Tags: php, html, sql-server, image, insert

im using php to create website and try to insert image from address to sqlserver database , im using this code :

```
function prepareImageDBString($filepath)
{
    $out = 'null';
    $handle = @fopen($filepath, 'rb');
    if ($handle)
    {        $content = @fread($handle, filesize($filepath));
        $content = bin2hex($content);
        @fclose($handle);
        $out = "0x".$content;
    }
    return $out;
}


$out = prepareImageDBString('http://....com/img.jpg');

sqlsrv_query($conn,"INSERT INTO Imagess(imgtype) VALUES($out) ");
```

image successful saving but not showing , i mean image Corrupted saved 
 how work to It's good to be saved?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20592796/1080354

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could use something like this to do it:

```
            $imgID = mysql_insert_id();
            $newname = "$imgID.jpg";
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'],"../images/product/$newname");
```