# Converting Image Data to Varbinary

Tags: ios, sql, sql-server, swift

I'm trying to upload image file on iOS device to remote SQL Server's VARBINARY(MAX) column but having difficulties.

Basically i need to convert UIImage to whatever i need to insert into:

```
INSERT INTO table (ImageColumn) VALUES ('byteString here')
```

Column type is: VARBINARY(MAX) and I can print string via:

```
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(value)
let base64String = imageData?.base64EncodedString()
imageBase64 = base64String!
print(imageBase64) // this prints all the string
```

this even writes 8-9mb of data to the column but it's always corrupted. I don't know if my sql query string is totally wrong or not

EDIT: quick fix

```
        let value_resized = value.resizedTo1MB()
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(value_resized!, 0)
        let strBase64 = imageData?.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
        imageBase64 = strBase64!
// i can insert imageBase64 to sql as a string

extension UIImage {

func resized(withPercentage percentage: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
    let canvasSize = CGSize(width: size.width * percentage, height: size.height * percentage)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(canvasSize, false, scale)
    defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
    draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: canvasSize))
    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
}

func resizedTo1MB() -> UIImage? {
    guard let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self) else { return nil }

    var resizingImage = self
    var imageSizeKB = Double(imageData.count) / 1000.0 

    while imageSizeKB > 1000 { 
        guard let resizedImage = resizingImage.resized(withPercentage: 0.9),
            let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(resizedImage)
            else { return nil }

        resizingImage = resizedImage
        imageSizeKB = Double(imageData.count) / 1000.0 
    }

    return resizingImage
}
}
```

Comment: Make sure you are not inserting varbinary data in quotes. That will convert it to varchar.

Comment: Are you sure that SQL Server is the correct location for this?  Usually it's better to host images, files, binaries, etc, in another location and the DB to hold the URLs, etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20592796/1080354

Comment: @HoneyBadger i've tried it but didn't work

Comment: Can you give an example how you tried it and what the result was? (Edit it in your question please)

Comment: I am having the same problem, did you ever get a solution?

Comment: yes i did though it's not optimal please see my edited question